# Floated div with uneven height align anchor tag inside horizontally

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have 3 floated divs (using foundation 5 ) with content inside.

Which are uneven in height all 3 floated div have a anchor tag inside as a button to open the page related to that content.

I want to align the anchor tag inside the div horizontally so all the buttons in the dive are in same line on large.

How it currently looks like - [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32L9ayor/3/)

The only way i can think of is adding another div inside for each div and give margin for each button, is there another way to achieve this? as this will be dynamic.

```
<div class="large-4 small-12 medium-12 columns">

    <div class="large-4 small-12 medium-4 columns text-center">
        <a href="page.html">
         <i> </i>
     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-8 small-12 medium-8 columns">
        <a href="social_it.html">
<h5>Heading</h5>
        </a>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint dolore illo quod reiciendis veritatis vitae unde nobis sequi eaque tempora natus architecto in hic aliquam ut at dolor perspiciatis consequatur?</p>

        <a class="btn-custom" href="page.html">Know more</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rpz24xvm/?

Comment: yes, i tried display:table-cell some how it does not work with foundation grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the Zurb's Equalizer: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

It you don't mind using js it's a great option for easily making divs equal height.

Here is the sample structure:

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a working example: http://codepen.io/nathanw/pen/EadQyN